# C++: type_info to distinguish types

Tags: c++, typeid, typeinfo

I know that compilers have much freedom in implementing `std::type_info` functions' behavior.

I'm thinking about using it to compare object types, so I'd like to be sure that:

1. `std::type_info::name` must return two different strings for two different types.
2. `std::type_info::before` must say that `Type1` is *before* `Type2` **exclusive-or** `Type2` is *before* `Type1`.

   ```
   // like this:
   typeid(T1).before( typeid(T2) ) != typeid(T2).before( typeid(T1) )
   ```
3. Two different specialization of the same template class are considered different types.
4. Two different `typedef`-initions of the same type are the same type.

And finally:

- Since `std::type_info` is not copyable, how could I store `type_info`s somewhere (eg: in a `std::map`)? The only way it to have a `std::type_info` always allocated somewhere (eg: on the stack or on a static/global variable) and use a pointer to it?
- How fast are `operator==`, `operator!=` and `before` on most common compilers? I guess they should only compare a value. And how fast is `typeid`?
- I've got a class `A` with a `virtual bool operator==( const A& ) const`. Since `A` has got many subclasses (some of which are unknown at compile time), I'd overload that virtual operator in any subclass `B` this way:

  ```
  virtual bool operator==( const A &other ) const {
    if( typeid(*this) != typeid(other) ) return false;
    // bool B::operator==( const B &other ) const // is defined for any class B
    return operator==( static_cast<B&>( other ) );
  }
  ```

  Is this an acceptable (and standard) way to implement such operator?

Comment: Note on part 2: definitely not if typeid(Type1) == typeid(Type2), i.e. they're not distinct types ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a quick look at the documentation, I would say that :

1. std::type_info::name always returns two different strings for two different types, otherwise it means that the compiler lost itself while resolving types and you shouldn't use it anymore.
2. Reference tells : "before returns true if the type precedes the type of rhs in the collation order. The collation order is just an internal order kept by a particular implementation and is not necessarily related to inheritance relations or declaring order."
   You therefore have the guarantee that no types has the same rank in the collation order.
3. Each instantiation of a template class is a different type. Specialization make no exceptions.
4. I don't really understand what you mean. If you mean something like having `typedef foo bar;` in two separate compilation units and that bar is the same in both, it works that way. If you mean `typedef foo bar; typedef int bar;`, it doesn't work (except if foo is int).

About your other questions :

- You should store references to std::type_info, of wrap it somehow.
- Absolutely no idea about performance, I assume that comparison operators have constant time despite of the type complexity. Before must have linear complexity depending on the number of different types used in your code.
- This is really strange imho. You should overload your `operator==` instead of make it virtual and override it.

Comment: About 4., I was meaning: `typedef a b; typedef a c;`, `typeid(b)==typeid(c)`? But yeah, I was sure even before posting the answer was yes. -- About `before`: I guess it could be constant time; it could be implemented like this: `return &typeid(a) < &typeid(b);`. -- About the last point: oops! I was of course meaning overload, not override.

Comment: About 4, of course if you type <code>typedef a b; typedef a c;</code>, a and c are of the same type.
About before, it depends if std::type_info is instantiated at compile time or runtime.

Comment: There is a conforming implementation of before that returns in constant time: take the addresses of the type_info objects, and compare them as integers. This may give differing results on different  runs of the same program, but that would still be conforming.

Comment: A conforming implementation may return the same name for different types.

Answer (score 4):

Standard 18.5.1 (Class type_info) :

> The class type_info describes type
>   information generated by the
>   implementation. Objects of this class
>   effectively store a pointer to a name
>   for the type, and an encoded value
>   suitable for comparing two types for
>   equality or collating order. **The
>   names, encoding rule, and collating
>   sequence for types are all unspecified
>   and may differ between programs**.

From my understanding :

1. You don't have this guarantee regarding `std:type_info::name`. The standard only states that `name` returns *an implementation-defined NTBS*, and I believe a conforming implementation could very well return the same string for every type.
2. I don't know, and the standard isn't clear on this point, so I wouldn't rely on such behavior.
3. That one should be a definite 'Yes' for me
4. That one should be a definite 'Yes' for me

Regarding the second set of questions :

- No, you cannot store a `type_info`. Andrei Alexandrescu proposes a `TypeInfo` wrapper in its [Modern C++ Design](http://books.google.com/books?id=aJ1av7UFBPwC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37) book. Note that **the objects returned by `typeid` have static storage** so you can safely store pointers without worrying about object lifetime
- I believe you can assume that `type_info` comparison are extremely efficient (there really isn't much to compare).

Comment: For (1), the string `""` is formally sufficient. It's null terminated, and the type is `const char[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can store it like this.

```
class my_type_info
{
public:
     my_type_info(const std::type_info& info) : info_(&info){}
     std::type_info get() const { return *info_;}
private:
     const std::type_info* info_;
};
```

EDIT:

C++ standard 5.2.8.

> The result of a
>   typeid expression is an lvalue of
>   static type const std::type_info...

Which means you can use it like this.

```
my_type_info(typeid(my_type));
```

The typeid function returns an lvalue (it is not temporary) and therefore the address of the returned type_info is always valid.

Comment: Yes, but where do I need to keep the value that `my_type_info::info_` points to? Doesn't it need to be always allocated (eg on the stack or on static/global variables)?

Comment: Ok, if it's static it's OK to store a pointer or a reference to a `type_info` returned by `typeid` even if such `type_info` gets removed from stack, thanks.

Comment: It cannot be removed from stack, since it never is on the stack.

Comment: The guarantee you're using is "The lifetime of the object referred to by the lvalue extends to the end of the program". The fact that the lvalue expression is of "static type" `const std::type_info` doesn't tell you anything about the lifetime of the object, and in particular doesn't mean that the *object* is static. "Static type" is defined in 1.3.11.

Comment: The standard says it's a "lvalue of static type".

Comment: @ronag. No it doesn't. It says it's an "lvalue of static type `const std::type_info`". You've removed half of a noun phrase, and pretty much invented your own definition of "static type" which differs from the definition in 1.3.11. An object's lifetime is almost completely unrelated to its type, or to the static type of an expression involving that object.

Comment: @ronag, you're right, since `typeid` returns a const reference (I was thinking it returned a `const type_info`, not a `type_info const &`. You must be right then :)

Comment: @Steve Jessop. You might be right. I don't quite understand. Will have to think about it. Either way, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: If it helps understand, the first part of that sentence could be rephrased: "The result of a typeid expression is an lvalue. The static type of the lvalue expression is `const std::type_info`. The most-derived type of the object to which the lvalue refers is `const std::type_info` or `const` *name* ... "

Comment: Thank you. That made it understandable for me.

Answer (score 2):

The current answers for questions 1 and 2 are perfectly correct, and they're essentially just details for the type_info class - no point in repeating those answers.

For questions 3 and 4, it's important to understand what precisely is a type in C++, and how they relate to names. For starters, there are a whole bunch of predefined types, and those have names: `int, float, double`. Next, there are some constructed types that do *not* have names of their own: `const int, int*, const int*, int* const`. There are function types `int (int)` and function pointer types `int (*)(int)`.

It's sometimes useful to give a name to an unnamed type, which is possible using `typedef`. For instance, `typedef int* pint` or `typedef int (*pf)(int);`. This introduces a name, not a new type.

Next are user-defined types: structs, classes, unions. There's a good convention to give them names, but it's not mandatory. Don't add such a name with typedef, you can do so directly: `struct Foo { };` instead of `typedef struct {} Foo;`. It's common to have class definitions in headers, which end up\ in multiple translation units. That does mean the class is defined more than once. This is still the same type, and therefore you aren't allowed to play tricks with macros to change the class member definitions.

A template class is *not* a type, it's a recipe for types. Two instantiations of a single class template are distinct types if the template arguments are different types (or values). This works recursively: Given `template <typename T> struct Foo{};`, `Foo<Foo<int> >` is the same type as `Foo<Foo<Bar> >` if and only if `Bar` is another name for the type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Type_info is implementation defined so I really wouldn't rely on it. However, based on my experiences using g++ and MSVC, assumptions 1,3 and 4 hold... not really sure about #2.

Is there any reason you can't use another method like this?

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_same       { static bool const result = false; };

template<typename T>
struct is_same<T, T> { static bool const result = true;  };

template<typename S, typename T>
bool IsSame(const S& s, const T& t) {   return is_same<S,T>::result; }
```

Comment: Oh right, I should have mentioned it doesn't work for polymorphism. That's a pretty good reason for not using it:D

Answer (score 1):

> Since std::type_info is not copyable, how could I store type_infos somewhere (eg: in a std::map)? The only way it to have a std::type_info always allocated somewhere (eg: on the stack or on a static/global variable) and use a pointer to it?

This is why `std::type_index` exists -- it's a wrapper around a `type_info &` that is copyable and compares (and hashes) by using the underlying type_info operations