# Runtime introspection in C++ - How does it work internally?

Tags: c++, class, introspection

I am looking for on information how runtime introspection in C++ works.

From what I have found so far is that additional information will be stored as run-time type information (RTTI) for each type. I could not find in what form this information is stored or how it is checked or accessed.

Thinking about it how does the introspection works if we have per se two very similar types e.g:

```
class TypeOne {
  string name;
}

class TypeTwo {
  string name;
}
```

What information will exactly be stored in memory so we can distinguish between the two types via introspection?

**TL;DR**
Looking for more information on how introspection is implemented.

**EDIT 1:**
Let's be clear that I do not need to know how to use introspection but rather how it is achieved. How the compilator generates the RTTI information? Is it stored per each object that is instantiated? Finally how RTTI is compared one to another during runtime?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++: type\_info to distinguish types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194191/c-type-info-to-distinguish-types)

Comment: there is nothing reading type info. please provide relevant example.

Comment: You will need to inspect the source code of your tool-chain - _"...The class `type_info` holds __implementation-specific__ information about a type,..."_ - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info

Comment: @ l000p Are you asking why compiler knows `typeid(TypeOne)` should return `type_info` for `TypeOne` not `TypeTwo`? what you think compiler would have hard time to do?

Comment: For these types, the compiler wouldn't even do runtime introspection. It would simply link directly to the hardcoded `type_info` at compile time. Your sample wouldn't involve any RTTI.

Comment: I don't understand.  The two classes are separate entities because they have distinct names, regardless of the content.  Are you asking how to determine the contents of class based on its name or TypeID?

Answer (score 0):

For g++ at least, it is pretty easy to see how typeinfo is implemented by looking at the generated assembly code.  For a program like:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%p\n", &typeid(main));
}
```

you get

```
        .weak   _ZTSFivE
        .section        .rodata._ZTSFivE,"aG",@progbits,_ZTSFivE,comdat
        .type   _ZTSFivE, @object
        .size   _ZTSFivE, 5
_ZTSFivE:
        .string "FivE"
        .weak   _ZTIFivE
        .section        .data.rel.ro._ZTIFivE,"awG",@progbits,_ZTIFivE,comdat
        .align 8
        .type   _ZTIFivE, @object
        .size   _ZTIFivE, 16
_ZTIFivE:
        .quad   _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__function_type_infoE+16
        .quad   _ZTSFivE
```

so for the typeid here, it has created a small (2 word) read-only object with a weak symbol in a 'comdat' section, along with a string that looks like a mangled name (also a weak symbol).  That means that if the same object gets created in multiple compilation units, they'll be combined into a single common object.  So you'll end up with exactly one typeinfo object for each distinct type referred to with typeid anywhere in the program.

Other implementations may be different.